# jquery back button to previous category in sortable gallery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I have a jquery portfolio gallery with 4 categories which are sortable. When you click on a category the portfolio is rearranged on the same page through jquery showing only those project in that category. Upon clicking a specific project the user can then see the project page/details. I want to add a back button on this page so that when a user is viweing a project they can return to category they were at before.

I tired the following which creates the back button but it take me back to the main portfolio page, not the category which I was browsing before.

```
function goBack() {
window.history.back();
}
```

This is one of the gallery page just in case: http://goo.gl/JeSNjD

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing any of your application's code, this is a bit of a shot in the dark but I think I know what you're probably missing.

Using the `history.back()` will take you to the last page you visited (a page visit is only recorded if the URL is updated). If you are updating content in your website with jQuery and not loading a new page, your browser's history doesn't record this so back takes you back to the top page still.

What you will need to do is change your back button code to hide the current project, and redisplay the category page. You cannot use `history.back()`.

**Edit:**
If you need more data to correctly rebuild the previous page, you can either change the url for the category page (not necessarily simple to implement but perhaps the most robust thing to do), or to store information about what page they came from. If you are using cookies, you could save navigation there, but you could also add a ref value to the query string when you navigate to a project page.

Category page:

```
<a href="/home/projectName?ref=categoryName">Link to project</a>
```

Project page:

```
<a href="/home?category=categoryName">Back button</a>
```

Then use that information to reopen or resort your categories.

Comment: When a category is clicked, the url does not change. However when a project is clicked, the url does change so a hide action after the url has changed wouldn't work in this scenario - I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I added additional info about how you might work that problem out.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is knowing which category a back button should return to.
For example, /portfolio/foothill-pasadena-2 should route back to the office category and /portfolio/131house should route back to the Residential category.  If I emailed you a link to one of those and you clicked it to go straight to the project page, should there be a back button on the page when you go to it and would it take you back to all categories or to the category related to the project?

One thing you could do is to change your permalink structure to include the category, such as /portfolio/office/foothill-pasadena-2 and /portfolio/residential/131house.  Then your could hard-code your back button to go to /projects.  You have some jquery running there (wp-content/themes/yourtheme/js/jquery.custom.js):

```
var isotopeContainer = jQuery('.portfolio-wrapper, .gallery-wrapper'),
isotopeFilter = jQuery('#filter'),
isotopeLink = isotopeFilter.find('a');
isotopeContainer.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.isotope-item',
    layoutMode : 'fitRows',
    filter : '.food-service'
});

isotopeLink.click(function () {
    var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-category');
    isotopeContainer.isotope({
        filter : '.' + selector,
        itemSelector : '.isotope-item',
        layoutMode : 'fitRows',
        animationEngine : 'best-available'
    });
    isotopeLink.removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

That is finding the four category links inside your filter div and adding a click function.

Maybe you can add some extra code that would get the document.referrer, checks it for a match against yoursite.com/new/projects/{category}/{project}, and pulls out the value of {category}.  If the category matches one of your four values (food-service, office, residential, other), then call the click function on that element.

Comment: to answer your question as to where the back button should go to, I think going back to the category would be good enough.  I can even call the button "Return to Category" so even if a link was emailed this would make sense. Could I then do it without changing the permalink?

Comment: Not in the way that I'm proposing.  Without the permalink change, you won't have a referrer value that gives your category page information about which category to auto-select.

Comment: Hmm, I just don't see how the write the categories to the url being they're not actual wordpress "categories", they are just jquery that perform the sort action on the page. In other words, changing my permalinks to /%postname%/%category% wouldn't allow me to call the categories by a unique url yoursite.com/{postname}/{category}/. Does that make sense?

Comment: Why not place them into actual categories, or tag them, or edit the individual links of each project?

Comment: Because I don't know how to place them in actual categories. The individual projects already have a unique url. The categories don't.

Comment: @user1724434, putting the projects into categories is easy.  In the wp-admin, just go to Posts -> Categories and add the four items.  Then in each Post (I'm assuming you have your Projects stored as posts, but they may be custom types), go to the edit screen, make sure Categories is selected to display (using the Screen Options), choose the proper category and save.  Now go to Settings -> Permalinks and add %category% to your permalink structure (e.g., /%category%/%postname%)